# Oracle.DataAccess (ODP.NET) Array Binding optimal block size

Tags: oracle, odp.net

Is there a way to calculate the optimal block size when using array binding to insert large amounts of data?

Comment: IMHO you can't say that in general as it depends on network latency and db performance (but glad to see recommendations). 
The slower the network and the faster the db the more you gain from increasing Execute Array count - at least up until a certain point where further improvements stall. After running lots of tests I decided on using 2.500 as default size. 
When running fast commands with simple parameters (raw 16, int) I sometimes increase to 10.000, resulting in 100.000+ records per second. When running slow commands with large strings and/or clobs, improvements may begin stalling at 500.

Comment: I guess I just have to test to get my sweet spot then.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this: When my application runs a command the first time I call this function:

```
Public Function GetRowSize(ByVal cmd As OracleCommand) As Integer
  Dim dr As OracleDataReader
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
  Return CInt(dr.GetType.GetField("m_rowSize", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(dr))
End Function
```

The result I store in a class variable for further use.
It is executed like this:

```
Dim cmd As OracleCommand
Dim da As OracleDataAdapter, dt As New DataTable
Dim expectedNumberOfRows As Integer

cmd = New OracleCommand("BEGIN :res := GetData(:expectedRows); END;"), server.con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("res", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)
cmd.Parameters.Add("expectedRows", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output)
cmd.Parameters("expectedRows").DbType = DbType.Int32

If rowSize = 0 Then rowSizes = GetRowSize(cmd)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
expectedNumberOfRows = CInt(cmd.Parameters("expectedRows").Value)
cmd.FetchSize = rowSize * expectedNumberOfRows
da = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(dt)
```

In my PL/SQL I run `EXPLAIN PLAN` in order to get the estimated number of rows, it looks like this:

```
FUNCTION GetData(estimatedRows OUT NUMBER) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    OPEN res FOR SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;

    DELETE FROM PLAN_TABLE;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE';
    SELECT CARDINALITY
    INTO estimatedRows
    FROM PLAN_TABLE
    WHERE ID = 0;

    RETURN res;

END;
```

Comment: I guess the question is about the size of the property OracleCommand.ArrayBindCount which can be used to execute a command for several values, saving network roundtrips.

Comment: Looks like I missed the question, my answer is more related to `SELECT` rather than `INSERT`